# Proving discontinuity by negation of continuity definition

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta

$f(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor$
A function $f$ is continuous at $x=a$ if:
$$\forall \epsilon >0 \ \ \exists \delta>0 \ \ \ \forall x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta) \ \ \ |f(x) - f(a)|<\epsilon.$$

The negation of this is
A function $f$ is discontinuous at x=a if:
$$\exists \epsilon >0 \ \ \ \forall \delta> 0 \ \ \ \exists x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta) \ \ \ |f(x) - f(a)| \geq \epsilon.$$

Prove that $f$ is discontinuous at $x=3$.

I just get lost in what to do first. Do I consider the $|f(x) - f(a)| \geq \epsilon$ part first? Do I pick $\epsilon$ first?

This is what I tried:
Pick $\epsilon$ to be $3$.Let $\delta>0$ be arbitrary and pick $x = 1-\delta < 3+\delta$.
Then  $f(1-\delta) \leq 0 $ so $f(1-\delta) - 3 \leq -3$ so  $|f(1-\delta) - 3| \geq 3 = \epsilon$.
I'm not sure if I just lucked out, but was my process correct? (Pick epsilon first, pick $x$...)

Comment: Was I valid in picking $x$? I feel like I'm not since $x$ is not in $(3-\delta,3+\delta)$.

Comment: Usually, you calculate $|f(x)-f(a)| \geq \epsilon$ to have an idea of which $\epsilon$, independent from $\delta$ to pick.

Comment: @Natash1: As you say, your choice of $x$ is invalid because it is not in $(3-\delta,3+\delta)$. You need to show that there is some $x$ in this interval such that this-and-that, and your $x$ is clearly not it. Earlier, you need to show that there is an $\epsilon$ such that this-and-that: Your peculiar choice of $\epsilon=3$ will not satisfy the requirements, you should pick one that is lesser than 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in an order. One must first pick the $\epsilon$, and then for all $\delta$, pick an $x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$ possibly depending on $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ such that $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$.

So, while doing this question, you should have an idea of what your $\epsilon$ is, first. What does this $\epsilon$ represent, is our question. How do we decide what value it is? To do this, we should understand how $\lfloor x \rfloor$ behaves in a neighbourhood of the point $3$.

Indeed, just to the left of $3$, it takes the value $2$, and to the right it takes the value $3$. So, in a neighbourhood of three, you can find a point whose function value is always separated from three by exactly one, simply by taking a point just to the left of three. This means, that you can always find a points, whose function value is separated from three , by more than, say one-half( any fraction smaller than one would have done here). This is in words. Now let's say it in symbols.

Let $\epsilon = \frac 12$. Let $\delta > 0$ be any positive number. Then, in the interval $(3-\delta,3+\delta)$, choose the number $x = 3-\frac{\delta}{2}$. This lies just enough to the left of three, and is also contained in the interval $(3-\delta,3+\delta)$. Of course, $\lfloor x\rfloor \leq 2$ by definition, but then $\lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor 3 \rfloor \geq 1 > \epsilon = \frac 12$. Hence, we have that $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is discontinuous at $x = 3$.

You can use this to prove that $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is actually discontinuous at all integers, and continuous everywhere else.

Comment: _"So, while doing this question, you should have an idea of what your $\epsilon$ is, first."_ Not necessarily. When finding a proof for *continuity*, one usually chooses $\delta$ as the last step of work, when you can see what $\delta$ you need, and then writes the proof down as if they had known the $\delta$ from the very beginning. Similarly, it's possible to find the proof for discontinuity by starting with a blank $\epsilon$, then figuring out the steps, and finally realizing what $\epsilon$ one should use to get the correct statement.

Comment: For large $\delta$ (which *I* of course know we need not consider), $\lfloor 3-\delta/2\rfloor=2$ will be wrong.

Comment: @JiK Indeed, you are correct.  I  think what I meant was, when we write a formal proof of discontinuity by negation, we must first mention what the candidate for $\epsilon$ is, although the thought process behind finding such an $\epsilon$ may involve plenty of work with potential $x$ and $\delta$ values. Also, I have edited the question to reflect what may happen for large $\delta$.

Answer (score 3):

$\epsilon = 3$ will not work. Specifically, if you pick $\epsilon = 3$, then I pick $\delta = 0.5$, and you only have $x\in (2.5, 3.5)$ to work with. You cannot make $|\lfloor x\rfloor - \lfloor 3 \rfloor|>3$ with that. Thus for that $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$, which means that your $\epsilon$ is *not* a witness to discontinuity.

If you look at the graph, it has jumps of length $1$, so you need to pick an $\epsilon<1$, say $\frac12$.

Once you've done that, you show that no matter which $\delta>0$ I throw at you, you can find aan $x\in (3-\delta, 3+\delta)$ such that $|f(x) - f(3)|<\frac12$. For instance, you might choose $3-\frac\delta2$, for this yields
$$
\left|\left\lfloor3-\frac\delta2\right\rfloor - \lfloor3\rfloor\right|\geq1>\frac12
$$
and we are done.

Comment: Thanks. i just did it but I wonder why $\epsilon < 1$ since I was able to choose $\epsilon = 1$?  
Here is what I did:  
  
let $x = 3-\frac{\delta}{2}$ then $f(3-\frac{\delta}{2}) \leq 2$ and so $|f(3-\frac{\delta}{2}) - 3| \geq 1$ so if I set $\epsilon = 1$ initially, then that function distance is $\geq \epsilon = 1$.

Comment: @Natash1 It is true that because the definition of continuity uses $|f(x) - f(a)|<\epsilon$ instead of $\leq \epsilon$, it will work with $\epsilon = 1$ in this case. I just like to leave a little margin. It's a habit of mine that doesn't matter here, but in many cases allows simplifications.